# Php and Ldap Login Authentication with uid

Tags: php, ldap

I want to create a user login authentication system using LDAP.what I need is, when a user enters his/her domain name and password it must redirect to another page as my connection is working but I can't able to bind the user, password, and, active directory. it's throwing me the error,
I have configured my php.ini file already.
So, where I'm getting wrong!!

```
<?php

   $ldap_dn = "uid=steve,ou=America,ou=Users,ou=MyUsers,dc=domain,dc=com";

    $ldap_password="steve_password";

    $ldap_con = ldap_connect("domain.com");

    ldap_set_option($ldap_con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    if(@ldap_bind($ldap_con,$ldap_dn,$ldap_password))
        echo "done";
    else
       echo "no!";
?>
```

Comment: Could you please remove the @ from @ldap_bind and tell us what error is thrown ?

Comment: fatal error......

Comment: I guess there must be some message after fatal error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing your connection to a directory server like this:

```
$ldap_con = ldap_connect("ldap://directoryserver.domain.com")
```